# AWS qna-bot returning messages with new line

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am working with the Cloudformation script from https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ai-qna-bot to build a chatbot. A lambda function is used to return a list of open jobs and the newline characters for python and html both are absorbed from the text but the new line does not appear. I've found that to fix this we must modify the message.vue file but I have been unable to find any fixes.
Here is what it currently looks like: [Chatbot Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLJN.png)